# In Shopify, how do I find and display the current product tag of a page?

Tags: shopify

For example, if I am on page URL:

collections/tableware/plates

I want to create a breadcrumb that says:

home >> tableware  >> plates

where tableware is a collection name and plates is a product tag. How do I pull up the current product tag (and only that product tag, I don't want to display all here)? Seems like it should be easy, but I still haven't figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [`current_tags`](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/current-tags) is what you're looking for:

> Inside collection.liquid, `current_tags` contains all **product tags** that are used to filter a collection.

For the URL `collections/some-collection/tag1`, `current_tags` contains `tag1`.

Note that `current_tags` is an array, and may contain multiple tags. For example, there are 3 current tags for this URL: `collections/some-collection/tag1+tag2+tag3`.

Comment: So how do I pick out one tag only out of the current_tags array?

Comment: You can use [`first`](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/array-filters#first), or the [index](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/array-filters#index).